# How to add a CSS class based on a condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to add a class for chips based on whether the values are valid or not. like this

[image]

For that added a flag variable to check whether the email is valid or not.

className={flag ? "chip-tag-error": "chip-tag"}

but there is no change in result instead invalid emails are added

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import './styles.css';


export const TagActions = () => {
    const [items, setItem] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const [error, setError]= useState('')
    const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false)

    const handleDelete = (item:any) => {
        console.log("handleDelete", item)
        const result = items.filter(i => i !== item)
        setItem(result)
      };
    
    const handleItemEdit = (item:any) =>{
        console.log("handleItemEdit", item)
        const result = items.filter(i => i !== item)
        setItem(result)
        setValue(item)
        console.log("value", value)
        
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (evt:any) => {
        if (["Enter", "Tab", ","].includes(evt.key)) {
          evt.preventDefault();

          var test = value.trim();
    
          if (test && isValid(test)) {
            items.push(test)
            setValue("")
           
          }
        }
    };

    const isValid = (email:any)=> {
        let error = null;
    
        if (isInList(email)) {
          error = `${email} has already been added.`;
        }
    
        if (!isEmail(email)) {
          setFlag(true)
          error = `${email} is not a valid email address.`;
        }
        
        if (error) {
            setError(error);
    
          return false;
        }
    
        return true;
    }

    const isInList = (email:any)=> {
        return items.includes(email);
      }
    
    const isEmail = (email:any)=> {
        return /[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/.test(email);
    }

    const handleChange = (evt:any) => {
        setValue(evt.target.value)
        // setError("")
        
    };

    const handlePaste = (evt:any) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
    
        var paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
        var emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/g);
    
        if (emails) {
          var toBeAdded = emails.filter((email:any) => !isInList(email));
            
            setItem(toBeAdded)
        
        }
    };
    


    return (
        <>
          <div>
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: items.map(item => (
              <Chip
                className={flag ? "chip-tag-error": "chip-tag"}
                key={item}
                tabIndex={-1}
                label={item}
                onDelete={() => handleDelete(item)}
                onClick={() => handleItemEdit(item)}
              />
            )),
  
          }}
            ref={divRef}
            value={value}
            placeholder="Type or paste email addresses and press `Enter`..."
            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            onPaste={(e) => handlePaste(e)}
          />
          </div>
  
          {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
        </>
      );
}
```

Styles.css

```
.chip-tag-error{
    color:red;
}
.chip-tag{
    color:blue;
}
```

Please give me a solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping problem.

If we look at this piece of your code you see that you have one value of `flag` for all items in the map. So you would have all items either valid or invalid.

```
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: items.map(item => (
              <Chip
                className={flag ? "chip-tag-error": "chip-tag"}
                key={item}
                tabIndex={-1}
                label={item}
                onDelete={() => handleDelete(item)}
                onClick={() => handleItemEdit(item)}
              />
            )),
  
          }}
```

What you need to do is compute the value of `flag` inside the map rather that on the whole set of items.

```
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: items.map(item => (
          <Chip
            className={!isEmail(item) ? "chip-tag-error": "chip-tag"}
            key={item}
            tabIndex={-1}
            label={item}
            onDelete={() => handleDelete(item)}
            onClick={() => handleItemEdit(item)}
          />
        )),

      }}
```

```
Two other notes:
 * It's always better to use strict typing on functions rather than use `any`
 * You have similar problems with your error states
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey try adding it like this:

```
className={`${flag ? "chip-tag-error": "chip-tag"}`}
```